# React app design: showing record counts for each page in navigation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, architecture

Building a react app (non-native, with Rails), where there's a side navigation with links to 6 pages.

Each page displays a set of records.

In the navigation I want to display the number of records (total, and new) for the page that link represents.

Should I try not to store the counts, but to run all the queries initially (pre-load) so I can get the counts?

Would you recommend having a parent component around the navigation and the main page that pre-loads and manages the data for the 6 pages so it can have the counts ready for the navigation to grab?

What about when the user removes an item from the page, would you just update the data in the parent component and skip any further db queries?

Or....?

Comment: You can either use a custom select query `Thing.joins(:other_things).select('things.*', 'count(other_things.id) AS other_things_count')` or [counter caches](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiKwpetx_nqAhUll4sKHaCMACwQFjAAegQIAxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fblog.appsignal.com%2F2018%2F06%2F19%2Factiverecords-counter-cache.html&usg=AOvVaw0IhFGXuv77BNnBV-JNbG96). The choice really boils down to read optimization vs the additional update queries needed to maintain caches and the risk of stale data of the count is critical.

Answer (score 0):

There are of course a number of ways this can be resolved and the optimal way can be subjective based on your specific needs. One possible way to set this up would be to:

1. Use [counter caches](https://blog.appsignal.com/2018/06/19/activerecords-counter-cache.html) to store the count as suggested by max.
2. On initial page load, query to find the count for all tabs and keep in state in the navigation bar.
3. For the data on the individual tabs, when data is created or removed just update the count in navigation bar with a callback function.

This way you won't have to run a query to count the items initially and then no further queries or complicated logic is required to keep the count up to date.